# Tic-tac-toe in python with OOP

Tags: python, object-oriented, tic-tac-toe, formatting

I'm a beginner to intermediate in programming, and created a Tic-tac-toe game in python. I plan to add an AI player and a GUI using pygame.

Any improvements I could make to the code, especially with the logic, or just formatting in general?

```
my_board = [
    ["1", "2", "X"],
    ["4", "5", "6"],
    ["7", "8", "9"]
]


class Tictactoe():
  def __init__(self, board):
    self.board = board
  
  def print_board(self):
    print("|-------------|")
    print("| Tic Tac Toe |")
    print("|-------------|")
    print("|             |")
    print("|    " + self.board[0][0] + " " + self.board[0][1] + " " + self.board[0][2] + "    |")
    print("|    " + self.board[1][0] + " " + self.board[1][1] + " " + self.board[1][2] + "    |")
    print("|    " + self.board[2][0] + " " + self.board[2][1] + " " + self.board[2][2] + "    |")
    print("|             |")
    print("|-------------|")
    print()

  def available_moves(self):
    moves = []
    for row in self.board:
      for col in row:
        if col != "X" and col != "O":
          moves.append(int(col))
    return moves

  def select_space(self, move, turn):
    row = (move-1)//3
    col = (move-1)%3
    self.board[row][col] = "{}".format(turn)

  def has_won(self, player):
    for row in self.board:
        if row.count(player) == 3:
            return True
    for i in range(3):
        if self.board[0][i] == player and self.board[1][i] == player and self.board[2][i] == player:
            return True
    if self.board[0][0] == player and self.board[1][1] == player and self.board[2][2] == player:
        return True
    if self.board[0][2] == player and self.board[1][1] == player and board[2][0] == player:
        return True
    return False
  
  def game_over(self):
    self.available_moves()
    if self.has_won("X") or self.has_won("O") or len(self.available_moves()) ==0:
      return True
    else:
      return False

  def get_player_move(self, turn):
    move = int(input("Player {player} make your turn: ".format(player=turn)))
    self.available_moves()
    while move not in range (1,10) or move not in self.available_moves():
      move = int(input("Invalid move, try again: "))
    return move
      

     
def game(board):
  tictactoe = Tictactoe(my_board)
  while not tictactoe.game_over():
    tictactoe.print_board()
    x_move = tictactoe.get_player_move("X")
    tictactoe.select_space(x_move,"X")
    tictactoe.print_board()
    if tictactoe.game_over():
      break

    o_move = tictactoe.get_player_move("O")
    tictactoe.select_space(o_move,"O")
  if tictactoe.has_won("X"):
    print("X wins")
  elif tictactoe.has_won("O"):
    print("O wins")
  else:
    print("tie")



game(my_board)
```

Answer (score 5):

---

**Indents**

[PEP 8: *Use 4 spaces per indentation level.*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)

---

**Main game loop**

The way your game loop is set up now is a bit unelegant. You already implemented all the methods to be able to handle both players, there's only one piece missing:

```
from itertools import cycle

players = cycle(['X', 'O'])
```

`cycle` will provide a generator that infinitely repeats the iterable you pass it. This makes the loop quite a bit cleaner:

```
while not tictactoe.game_over():
    tictactoe.print_board()

    player = next(players)
    move = tictactoe.get_player_move(player)
    tictactoe.select_space(move, player)
```

I'd also suggest renaming `select_space` to something like `do_move`. Makes it a bit clearer what's going on.

---

**Redundant calls to `Tictactoe.available_moves()`**

In `game_over` and `get_player_move` you call `self.available_moves()` once without using the return value in any way. You can simply delete those lines.

---

**`game_over`**

The pattern

```
if self.has_won("X") or self.has_won("O") or len(self.available_moves()) ==0:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

can be simplified to

```
return self.has_won("X") or self.has_won("O") or len(self.available_moves()) == 0
```

What you were doing is basically manually returning the resulting `bool` value of a condition. We can instead simply return the condition directly.

---

**`print_board`**

Python lets you easily avoid an unelegant pattern

```
print("|    " + self.board[0][0] + " " + self.board[0][1] + " " + self.board[0][2] + "    |")
```

by using the `*` operator for unpacking an iterable

```
print("|   ", *self.board[0], "   |")
```

Since we need to do this for all rows in `self.board` we should let Python handle it for us as well:

```
for row in self.board:
    print("|   ", *row, "   |")
```

---

**has_won**

For a cleaner implementation of this method I would suggest implementing helper functions that provide lists of the rows, columns and diagonals of the board. They might also be useful for future feature additions.

```
def rows(self):
    return self.board[:]  # creates a mutable copy of the rows

def columns(self):
    return [[row[index] for row in self.board] for index in range(3)]

def diagonals(self):
    first = [self.board[index][index] for index in range(3)]
    second = [self.board[index][len(self.board[index]) - index - 1] for index in range(3)]
    return [first, second]
```

These methods are also ready to be used for boards of different sizes. Simply replace the `3`s by a variable.

`has_won` is now a lot simpler and more readable:

```
def has_won(self, player):
    for line in self.rows() + self.columns() + self.diagonals():
        symbols = set(line)
        if player in symbols and len(symbols) == 1:
            return True

    return False
```

We can take this a step further (as pointed out in the comments) and change `has_won` to `get_winner` and return the winning symbol. This will also affect some other parts of your code:

`class Tictactoe`:

```
def get_winner(self):
    for line in self.rows() + self.columns() + self.diagonals():
        symbols = set(line)
        if len(symbols) == 1:
            return symbols.pop()

    return None


def game_over(self):
    return self.get_winner() is not None or len(self.available_moves()) == 0
```

Printing our winner in `game`:

```
def game(...):
    
    # main gameplay here
    
    if (winner := self.get_winner()) is not None:
        print(f"{winner} wins")
    else:
        print("tie")
```

Comment: Plenty of good advice here. In addition, the OP could consider another simplification of has_won(): unless I've overlooked something, it doesn't need the player argument: if all symbols are the same (and not empty), someone has one; just return who it is.

Comment: Very good suggestion, I added it to my answer!

Answer (score 2):

one performance improvement suggestion

**available_moves**

Instead of iterating through all the moves create a `set` with all the moves in the beginning and as each player makes a move remove the corresponding move from the set.

In your code both iterating through all moves to find the valid moves(`available_moves` function) and then the checking if the move given is valid (`move not in self.available_moves()`) both of this are **o(n)** operations. But using set I believe both these operation could average to **o(1)**.

Might not be a huge difference in performance considering tic tac toe only has 9 moves. But might be a good way to tackle the problems in other similar situations.