# Tic Tac Toe (new draft)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I have implemented suggestion and created new draft of the Tic Tac Toe program. Please review and let me know where I can improve.

```
import random

def update_board():
    """Play game"""
    board = [[3 * row + col for col in range(1, 4)] for row in range(3)]

    total_count = 0
    UserTurn = False

    while total_count < 9:
        available_number = remaining_num(board)
        message = ''
        if total_count == 0 :
            board[1][1] = 'X'
            UserTurn = True
        elif UserTurn == False :
            #Computer's Turn
            num = random.choice(available_number)
            num_indx = find_index(num, board)
            board[num_indx[0][0]][num_indx[0][1]] = 'X'
            UserTurn = True
        elif UserTurn == True :
            #User's Turn
            UserTurn = False
            num = int(input(f'select number {available_number}: '))
            num_indx = find_index(num, board)
            if num_indx:
                board[num_indx[0][0]][num_indx[0][1]] = 'O'
            else :
                print('Selected number is invalid!')
        total_count += 1
        message = check(board, message)
        if message:
            draw_board(board)
            print(message)
            break
        elif message == '' and len(available_number) <= 1:
            draw_board(board)
            print('Tie !!')
            break
        draw_board(board)


def find_index(num,board):
    """Find index of the number"""
    num_indx = [[indx1, indx2] for indx1, val1 in enumerate(board)
                for indx2, val2 in enumerate(val1)
                if val2 == num]
    return num_indx

def remaining_num (board):
   """Available number list."""
   avail_num = [board[i][j] \
                for i in range(len(board)) \
                for j in range(len(board)) \
                if board[i][j] not in ('X', 'O')]
   return avail_num



def check(board,message):
    """Ckeck for win."""
    if board[0][0] == board[0][1] == board[0][2] == 'X' or \
       board[1][0] == board[1][1] == board[1][2] == 'X' or \
       board[2][0] == board[2][1] == board[2][2] == 'X' or \
       board[0][0] == board[1][0] == board[2][0] == 'X' or \
       board[0][1] == board[1][1] == board[2][1] == 'X' or \
       board[0][2] == board[1][2] == board[2][2] == 'X' or \
       board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] == 'X' or \
       board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0] == 'X' :
                message = 'Computer win !!'
    elif board[0][0] == board[0][1] == board[0][2] == 'O' or \
         board[1][0] == board[1][1] == board[1][2] == 'O' or \
         board[2][0] == board[2][1] == board[2][2] == 'O' or \
         board[0][0] == board[1][0] == board[2][0] == 'O' or \
         board[0][1] == board[1][1] == board[2][1] == 'O' or \
         board[0][2] == board[1][2] == board[2][2] == 'O' or \
         board[0][0] == board[1][1] == board[2][2] == 'O' or \
         board[0][2] == board[1][1] == board[2][0] == 'O' :
                message = 'User win !!'
    return message

def draw_board(board):
    """Draw board"""
    for i in range(3):
        print('+' + '-' * 5 + '+' + '-' * 5 + '+' + '-' * 5 + '+', )
        print('|' + ' ' * 5 + '|' + ' ' * 5 + '|' + ' ' * 5 + '|')
        for j in range(3):
            print('| ' + str(board[i][j])+ ' ' * 3, end='')
        print('|')
        print('|' + ' ' * 5 + '|' + ' ' * 5 + '|' + ' ' * 5 + '|')
    print('+' + '-' * 5 + '+' + '-' * 5 + '+' + '-' * 5 + '+')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    update_board()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) naming conventions when naming variables and functions.

---

`user_turn == False` should be `user_turn is False`, or even better `not user_turn`. `user_turn == True` should simply be `user_turn`, since `bool_var == (bool_var == True)`.

---

**`check`**

Why do you pass `message` as an argument, if you just overwrite it? Seems like you actually want a default argument: `def check(board, message='')`.

That amount of code duplication should always raise a red flag. Writing these conditions out manually is error-prone and hurts maintainability / scalability. You could take some inspiration from a [previous answer of mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/259817/239401) (which I'm sure can be further improved) or some other threads on CodeReview.

---

**`draw_board`**

Pulling out separator and empty rows could already make this a whole lot more readable and maintainable. This is an improved version, not yet perfect by any means:

```
def build_row(sep, fill):
    return f"{sep}{sep.join([fill * 5] * 3)}{sep}"


def draw_board(board):
    sep_row = build_row(sep='+', fill='-')
    empty_row = build_row(sep='|', fill=' ')

    for i in range(3):
        print(sep_row)
        print(empty_row)

        for j in range(3):
            print('| ' + str(board[i][j]) + ' ' * 3, end='')

        print('|')
        print(empty_row)

    print(sep_row)
```

---

**General approach**

Your approach using `find_index`, `remaining_num` seems overcomplicated in some places. You could simply keep a `list` of the remaining numbers and remove each number once a symbol is placed on it.